# Grails 2.1 Join Query

Tags: grails

I m new user in Grails. I don't know how to write projection query. Here is my code. please anyone help me for grails projection query.

From Join table I want to find username which is consist in user table

Given the following example domains:

```
class User{
transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
boolean enabled
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

 static mapping = {
    table 't04t001'
    id              column: 'f_account_id'
    username        column: 'f_username',       length: 10
    password        column: 'f_password',       length: 100
    enabled         column: 'f_account_active'
    accountExpired  column: 'f_account_expired'
    accountLocked   column: 'f_account_locked'
    passwordExpired column: 'f_password_expired'
    version         column: 'f_revision'
 }
}

class Role{

String role
static mapping = {
    table 't04t003'
    id              column : 'f_role_id'
    role            column : 'f_role'
    version         column : 'f_revision'
    cache true
}
}


class UserRole implements Serializable {

    User user
    Role role

    static mapping = {
        table 't04j002'
        id              composite   : ['role', 'user']
        role            column      :'k_role_id'
        user            column      :'k_user_id'
        version false
    }    
    }
```

I can't figure out how to build the criteria to find all the user. I tried the following:

```
    def criteria    = UserRole.createCriteria()
    def list        = criteria.list {  
        projections { 
            user{
                ilike('username', 'omar')
            }  
        }            
    }
```

In console mode i have seen this query with message

```
Hibernate: 
select
    this_.k_role_id as k1_3406_0_,
    this_.k_user_id as k2_3406_0_ 
from
    t04j002 this_ 
where
    (
        lower(user_alias1_.f_username) like ?
    )
```

However, it says  Unknown column 'user_alias1_.f_username' in 'where clause'.

But i cant figure out this(user_alias1_) alias

Comment: Which one is the `user` domain?

Comment: I hope you have a good reason for naming domain classes/tables this way :-)

Comment: You can still use your table name like this, but do a meaningfull name for your Domain Class. It will make your code more readable.

Comment: What a cluster. Please name your domains something that means something.

Comment: Thanks all who are response. Now I edit my domain class and Join table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear on what you want to retrieve from which table. So based on your criteria query, here is how to retrieve `user` from the `UserRole` table.

```
def criteria = UserRole.createCriteria()
def result = criteria.list {
    projections {
        property("user") 
    }
    user {
        eq("username", "omar") //strict match
    }
}
return result;
```

What this does is it builds a list that has the `user.username` as `omar`. By default the result will be the `UserRole` object, but to get `user` object instead we used projections.

Update:
Your Domain class seems a bit out of grails conventions. Why not user something like this?

```
//User.groovy
class User {
    String username
    // ..
    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize: 10
    }
}

//UserRole.groovy
// Since you are using composite keys, we have to implement serializable. But is there a need for composite key in your situtation?
class UserRole implements Serializable {
    User user
    // ..
}
```

In you service class

```
// UserRoleService.groovy
def getUser(String username) {
    def criteria = UserRole.createCriteria()
    def result = criteria.get {
        projections {
            property("user") 
        }
        user {
            ilike("username", username)
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And to call the service method from controller,

```
// ExampleController.groovy
class ExampleController {
    def userRoleService

    def index() {}
    def someThing(String username) {
        def user = userRoleService.getUser(username)
        println user?.username
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to retrieve username from User table by using UserRole(join table) table

Comment: I have tried this code but still this problem ( Unknown column 'user_alias1_.f_username' in 'where clause')